# Code working on local but not on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have written a small piece of code in NodeJS to update a MongoDB collection. The code works fine when I run it on my local machine. But once deployed to AWS it doesn't

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log("I am here");

  const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
  const uri =
    "xxxxxxx";
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);

  async function run() {
    console.log("Inside the function");
    try {
      const database = client.db("mydb");
      const movies = database.collection("TACountryMapping");
      // create a filter for a movie to update
      var filter = { Key: "Value" };
      // this option instructs the method to create a document if no documents match the filter
      const options = { upsert: true };
      // create a document that sets the plot of the movie
      const updateDoc = {
        $set: { Key: "updatedValue", address: "Canyon 123" },
      };
      const result = await movies.updateOne(filter, updateDoc, options);

      console.log(result);
      console.log(
        `${result.matchedCount} document(s) matched the filter, updated ${result.modifiedCount} document(s)`
      );
    } finally {
      await client.close();
    }
  }

  run().catch(console.dir);
  return 0;
};

//exports.handler();
```

The result object just doesn't seem to be getting created in lambda.

Following are the logs when running the code from my local machine:

```
I am here
Inside the function
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
1 document(s) matched the filter, updated 1 document(s)
```

And when run from Lambda, the following are the logs:

```
START RequestId: 3cdc0764-7238-4218-bdf2-954556f10c77 Version: $LATEST
2022-12-04T03:18:56.383Z 3cdc0764-7238-4218-bdf2-954556f10c77 INFO  I am here
2022-12-04T03:18:56.505Z 3cdc0764-7238-4218-bdf2-954556f10c77 INFO  Inside the function
END RequestId: 3cdc0764-7238-4218-bdf2-954556f10c77
REPORT RequestId: 3cdc0764-7238-4218-bdf2-954556f10c77  Duration: 478.33 ms Billed Duration: 479 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 78 MB
```

I have tried to remove the `await` from `await movies.updateOne(filter, updateDoc, options);`, but that just skips the code entirely and doesn't work

Comment: `await run().catch(console.dir);`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are awaiting for the `movies.updateOne` statement but not awaiting for the entire `run()` function to complete before ending the execution of the lambda.

> When a Lambda function doesn't wait for the event loop to be empty and a container is re-used, the event loop will be "paused" until the next invocation occurs.

Try refactoring your code to what is shown below. Note the use of `await run()` statement that will make sure the entire code has completed execution before ending execution.

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log("I am here");

  const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
  const uri ="xxxxxxx";
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);

  await run();
  return 0;
};

async function run() {
  console.log("Inside the function");
  try {
    const database = client.db("mydb");
    const movies = database.collection("TACountryMapping");
    // create a filter for a movie to update
    var filter = { Key: "Value" };
    // this option instructs the method to create a document if no documents match the filter
    const options = { upsert: true };
    // create a document that sets the plot of the movie
    const updateDoc = {
      $set: { Key: "updatedValue", address: "Canyon 123" },
    };
    const result = await movies.updateOne(filter, updateDoc, options);

    console.log(result);
    console.log(
      `${result.matchedCount} document(s) matched the filter, updated ${result.modifiedCount} document(s)`
    );
  }
  catch(e){
    console.error(e);
  }
  finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
```

**P.S:** I'm assuming your connection to the database is working fine here and no connection errors were noticed in `AWS Cloudwatch`.